# Liquibase issue when using synonyms

Tags: liquibase

I have two schemas: OWNER & USER in my Oracle database. Basically, all tables are created in OWNER, and after it synonyms are created using USER account.

```
<execution>
    <id>apply.owner</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <url>${database.url}</url>
        <username>${database.owner.user}</username>
        <password>${database.owner.password}</password>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
        <changeLogFile>${changelog.owner.file}</changeLogFile>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>

<execution>
    <id>apply.user</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <url>${database.url}</url>
        <username>${database.user.user}</username>
        <password>${database.user.password}</password
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
        <changeLogFile>${changelog.user.file</changeLogFile>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

DATABASECHANGELOG(LOCK) tables were created for OWNER account, synonyms for USER account were added, and I am able to see them in SQL developer. But when I'm running initial migration for USER schema I got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.8:rollback (apply.user) on project liquitest: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liq
uibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, LOCKED NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMES
TAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR2(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges -> [Help 1]
```

Why it tries to create this table when I can select from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table using USER account?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase checks the database metadata for the existence of the databasechangelog table, but it does not have functionality to look at synonyms, unfortunately.

If you need to have USER.DATABASECHANGELOG as a synonym, you would need to create a subclass of liquibase.snapshot.jvm.TableSnapshotGenerator that can handle synonyms or hard-codes a response for the DATABASECHANGELOG table.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! I though that there are some issues with synonyms, thanks for confirmation. And can liquibaseSchemaName/liquibaseTableName help me with having DATABASECHANGELOG(LOCK) table in another schema?

Comment: Yes, those parameters allow you to set what schema the DATABASECHANGELOG and LOCK tables are in if they are in a different schema than your normal default schema.

Comment: LIquibase's snapshot and diff logic doesn't yet try to get into database-specific features which snapshot is, which is why it doesn't work well.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! I'll try with schemaName/tableName.

Comment: Finally, these settings were required to use correct schema for changelog tables : <changelogSchemaName>OWNER</changelogSchemaName>
                               <changelogCatalogName>OWNER</changelogCatalogName>

Comment: I am running into the same problem, and curious: here did you set changelogSchemaName and changelogCatalogName?